# The first number larger than $N$ in prime gap sequence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Is there any way to estimate the first number in the prime gap sequence which is greater than a given number $N$?

For example, for $N=3$, $g_4=11-7=4$ is the first one larger than $N$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A005250 is a relevant sequence.

Comment: No there is no way. But if you replace the primes by [a random model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification) then  you can make some conjectures.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I can tell you that  if you want $n-1$ consecutive numbers which are *surely* composite you can take $$n!+2,n!+3,\ldots,n!+n$$
Contemplate the arid prairie of $10^{100}-1$ consecutive composite numbers going from $$1googol!+1,\ldots, 1googol!+1googol$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stand on the shoulders of a giant, [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5110).
There is a large prime gap between $n!+2$ and $n!+n$, this is completely elementary.
Erdos and Rankin used sieve methods to improve such bound, and the mentioned article by Maynard is a further improvement. In any case, this is a classical and pretty difficult problem, far from being completely settled.